# Dump Object - Get function returned value instead of 'function'?

Tags: javascript, function, return

I found a object dump function for JavaScript (alternative to PHP print_f()). I have an object with a single function - myFunction(); Here's the code I use to 'dump' all the functions:

```
if(typeof(obj) == 'object') { 
   for(var item in obj) {

      if(typeof(value) == 'function'){
          var value = obj[item]; // !!!???
          alert(value);
      }

   }
}
```

The problem is line 'var value = obj[item];' returns "**function myFunction() { try {..**" instead of the actual 'myFunction()' return value. How can I call the function from my code and get return value instead of the actual code? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Change the line to:

`var value = obj[item]();`

You need to call the function, so you use the parens

Answer (score 0):

Use `()` like so

```
var value = obj[item]();
```

If you want to pass arguments, just put them between the parentheses

```
var value = obj[item](arg1, arg2);
```

You can think of `()` as a call operator. Function in Javascript are object and you *call* them using the `()` operator.

Comment: Wow, that was fast. Thank you both. What about if I want to pass an argument, simply obj[item](Args);? Thanks!